# Why log in with facebook , url not ok?

Tags: php, url, facebook-php-sdk

When i log in with facebook , it's will get url

for example

```
http://www.vasplus.info/demos/login_with_fb/index.php#_=_
```

OR

```
http://stackoverflow.com/#_=_
```

what does it mean `#_=_` in url ?

Comment: you got any issue when u have #_=_  in url ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem has been resolved in this stackoverflow. The problem you've mentioned has been ask in the past.

Try and see this: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/552/

> **Change in Session Redirect Behavior**
>
> This week, we started adding a fragment #*=* to the redirect_uri when this field is left blank. 
>           Please ensure that your app can handle this behavior.

Answer (score -1):

it is because mostly you haven't set the application namespace and refrenece url in the facebook.

when you create app on facebook go to settings of app and set the namespace of the application which will include your domain so that facebook can determine the correct call of app, and reference url on which user will be redirected after successful login

Comment: Namespace cannot fill ulr because can not fill (.) full stop

Comment: namespace is something like the directory where your file is present dont give the name of file in url! like if you file is in www.domain.com/facebook/fblogin.php then your name space will be www.domain.com/facebook